# How to write a Know_hosts file with md5 format?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, ssh-keys, known-hosts

I am trying to make a program that automates ssh connections. It can also be used in Windows, so as Putty only accepts MD5 fingerprint format for the hostkey I am trying to make ssh accept MD5 too:

My command on ubuntu 18.04:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=myknownhosts -o FingerprintHash=md5  ubuntu@1.2.3.4
```

myknownhosts format:

```
256 MD5:57:fb:dc:8f:25:29:1a:f7:1f:aa:c8:12:fc:bf:8a:XX 1.2.3.4 (ED25519)
2048 MD5:73:37:38:38:d8:4f:3b:9e:41:2e:9a:12:a8:49:92:XX 1.2.3.4 (RSA)
256 MD5:37:3b:87:29:6b:7f:81:1a:15:85:1b:12:49:8d:f7:XX 1.2.3.4 (ECDSA)
```

This is the ouput of:

```
ssh-keygen -lf testhost.ssh-keyscan -E md5
```

Which testhost.ssh is the public key of 1.2.3.4

The problem is that SSH is unable to auto authenticate, after the first command it keeps printing the MD5 fingerprint and asking if I am sure:

```
 Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
```

I reckon the problem is with the `myknownhosts` format as if I saved with sha256 format it works. Is there any special format for md5 fingerprints?

Of course I don't want to use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

Comment: What does the "working" format look like exactly?

Comment: If you use the parameter `HashKnownHost=no`: 
1.2.3.4 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 here_goes_the_ecdsa_sha2_public_key_format

Comment: Ah, but that isn't a fingerprint, it's the whole public key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "sha256 format" or "md5 format" for the known_hosts file. OpenSSH doesn't accept key fingerprints in the file at all, no matter their type – it has always required **the full public key** to be listed. You need to skip the `ssh-keygen -l` conversion step completely.

OpenSSH only uses fingerprints for display purposes (e.g. in the "Do you know this server" confirmation dialog), and options such as 'FingerprintHash' only change the appearance of those messages – they do not affect any file formats.

The only way to use an MD5 fingerprint for automation would be:

1. Obtain the full public key.
2. Compare the obtained key's fingerprint with the user-provided fingerprint.
3. If they match, write the full public key to the known_hosts file.

Comment: Thank you, now I get it. I was wrong because I thought that in known_hosts file it was saved the fingerprint, either sha256 or md5, not the full public key. So, what OpenSSH does when a ssh connection is performed is: make the fingerprint of the known_hosts key(if exists), make the fingerprint of the destination and compare if they match?

Comment: The SSH client just directly compares the whole keys, it doesn't need to hash them into a fingerprint. (Fingerprints are used so that _people_ could compare them easier, because the actual keys are usually quite long.)

Comment: Great! Thank you so much